# What is the general ruling on baduas? ( making negative duas on someone )

Tags: sharia, dua

What is the general ruling on baduas? ( making negative duas on someone )

if someone has caused you so much harm that you feel anger and hate towards them to an extent that you want Allah to deal with them, and that you can not forgive them.

Is it allowed? and do you get punished on day of judgement for making such duas?

Answer (score 1):

> And the retribution for an evil act is an evil one like it, but whoever pardons and makes reconciliation - his reward is [due] from Allah . Indeed, He does not like wrongdoers. (Qur'an Ch. 42, V 40)
>
> And if you punish [an enemy, O believers], punish with an equivalent of that with which you were harmed. But if you are patient - it is better for those who are patient. (Qur'an Ch. 16, V 126)
>
> Tell those who believe to forgive those who hope not for the days of Allah; in order that He may requite folk what they used to earn. (Qur'an Ch. 45, V 14)
>
> So be patient with gracious patience.  (Qur'an Ch. 70, V 5)

So, based on the above verses, it is highly advisable that you forgive them.

**Support:**
[Your Modern Islam](http://yourmodernislam.blogspot.com/)

May the creator guide us all.